# How to assign php variable value into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have below js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jvalue = 'Hi, $name';
</script>
```

And this is my php code

```
<?php
    $name= "Rama";
    $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>";
    echo $abc;
?>
```

This is giving me output

```
Hi, $name
```

Instead of

```
Hi, Rama
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo` it. But Remember to follow the sequence of definition -

```
<?php
    $name= "Rama";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jvalue = 'Hi, <?php echo $name; ?>';
</script>

<?php
$abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>";
echo $abc;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This one

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jvalue = "Hi, <?=$name;?>";
</script>
```

User double cot.

or best you can assing that php varible in input like this

```
<input type=hidden value="<?=$name; ?>" id='name'>
```

so you can access value of input using id anywhare on page. 
your script code will be

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          var jvalue = 'Hi, '+$('#name').val()+'';
        });
    </script>
```

I hope it will work for u as easy solution for now and for future.

Answer (score 1):

simple... try this

```html
<?php 
$variable = "JS";
?>

<script>
   var field = <?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>;
  </script>
```